# Which wallets will usedapp activateBrowserWallet connect to?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

https://usedapp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core.html#useethers says

> activateBrowserWallet(onError?: (error: Error) => void, throwErrors?: boolean) - function that will initiate connection to browser web3 extension (e.g. Metamask)

So, that function at least connects to Metamask. Which other extensions/wallets will this function connect to?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use this library. The docs are terribly out of date.